# What should the "about" say for the [security] tag?

Tags: discussion

I like this new "about" statement for all tags.   It makes them more defined.  So what should it say for the [security] tag?   I just put "This tag is used for topics relating to attacks against software.",  but you might disagree.  What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I want to say that there's more to security than just 'attacks', but then when I go through various counter-examples, it ends up being in part related to attacks.  It still has slightly the wrong emphasis, so maybe:

- The security tag is used for questions relating to attacks on software and how write programs to ensure that attacks are not successful.

With, maybe, a caveat that 'recovering from a successful attack is more appropriately discussed on ServerFault or SuperUser'.

Answer (score 1):

I think that algorithm types relating to security should be mentioned.

I'm not sure what the broad categories are, maybe things like encryption (hashing, salting...),captchas?, random number generation.... Just 3 or so broad and important categories.

Comment: +1 i agree to an extent,  there is actually a cryptography and encryption and there is a lot of overlap.  For instance encryption always relates to cryptography  and both always relate to security,  but i don't think SO allows us to build such a relation tree....

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the tag info page should, as a subset, contain links to the things most likely to interest newbies and people looking for urgent help: Links to the best "So your site's been hacked" type of resources (and if most of the answers to that question are on serverfault - then link there.)

Comment: +1 i agree there are some panicked posts.

Comment: @Pekka, you mean like an faq, http://stackoverflow.com/tags/security/faq that is linked below the description?

Comment: @waffles basically yes, but most "my site's been hacked" questions are over on serverfault, and won't turn up in the SO security faq. Those would require some sort of a manually edited list

Comment: @Pekka I'm not sure we want to use that space to drive users to other sites, but you do raise an interesting point / concept ... ability to browse another sites questions/answers on the same tag (provided they are close)

Comment: @Pekka ... also I do not think these lists are interesting when mixed ... http://serverfault.com/tags/security/faq http://superuser.com/tags/security/faq  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/security/faq

Comment: @waffles i agree to a large extent mainly because it takes a programmer to write a patch.  Sure a sys admin can clean up the infection,  but he is just going to get hacked again.  *shrug*